# Pausing and Recreating timers with notifications issue Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, timer, nstimer

So I've got two timers, one that increases the score and one that spawns enemies. I used a notification to invalidate the timers, and then I'm using another one to recreate the timers. When I quit and then open the app, there are two sets of enemies being spawned on top of each other. I think timerRecreate = true and also the regular timers in GameScene are also being called.

GameViewController.swift file:

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("pauseTimers:"), name:UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification, object: nil)

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("startTimers:"), name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification, object: nil)
}
func pauseTimers(notification : NSNotification) {
    println("Observer method called")
    timer.invalidate()
    scoretimer.invalidate()
}

func startTimers(notification : NSNotification) {
    println("Observer method called")
    timerRecreate = true
}
```

Code for timers in GameScene.swift

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    //Spawn timer for enemy blocks
    timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.4, target: self, selector: Selector("spawnEnemies"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    //Timer for keeping score
    scoretimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.1, target: self, selector: Selector("scoreCounter"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */

    if timerRecreate == true {
        //Spawn timer for enemy blocks
        timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.4, target: self, selector: Selector("spawnEnemies"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

        //Timer for keeping score
        scoretimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.1, target: self, selector: Selector("scoreCounter"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        timerRecreate = false
    }
    }
```

I think the problem is when you initially open the app, be that after quitting out of it or opening it for the first time, timerRecreate is set to true as well as the regular spawning of blocks so two sets of blocks are spawned at the same time. How can I fix this?

Comment: You are setting the target to a new instance of GameScene - this should be `self`, and the notification methods should also be in GameScene.

Comment: Every time you do call `GameScene()`, you're creating new object. You probably have `GameScene` object somewhere, then your score timer fires on another `GameScene` object, enemies time fires on another `GameScene` object, ... You should create your `GameScene` object once and then reuse it - singleton, property of your `GameViewController`, ...

Comment: did you ever start the timer?

Comment: Ok editing my code now.

Comment: @JoshHamet `NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval` starts timer automatically, just read the docs ...

Comment: Sort of fixed the problem but another one arose in the process. Edited my post accordingly.

Comment: Why is the target once `self` and once `GameScene()`? This alone looks broken. The setup code should in both cases be identical IMHO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it! I hope...

Anyway heres what I did. I created another boolean called timerz and set it to false when the DidBecomeActive notification was made. At the same time, timeRecreate is set to true. This guarantees that both timer sets arent running at the same time. In the update function inside the if statement on whether timRecreate was true, I set timeRecreate to false and timerz to true. So the timers are recreated and then it switches back to to old way of spawning them. I also put this old method of spawning them inside an if statement on whether timerz was true or false.